# File shortcuts don't work or throwing association error in Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-11, shortcuts, file-shortcut

I accidentally broke up my Windows 11 registry regarding shortcuts. To be honest, I also forgot to export a copy of the registry before making changes. Yeah, I know it's dumb, but it happened.

I overlooked that I pasted one wrong key into .reg file and I deleted everything under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers`

And now shortcuts to folders don't work at all, just nothing happens without any error or something.

Clicking any pinned app on the taskbar, however, gives me this error - https://i.stack.imgur.com/72hWv.png. It's in polish, but in short, it means that this action can't be done because there is no association between the application and the file and then there is a hint to install the application and add an association in the settings.

I suspect this is some kind of shared error message, so it could work on other file types, but rather not on *.lnk files which are handled by the system, and as far as I know, there is no way to create this association in settings.

So here are my questions. Are these values common in every installation, so someone of you could share them or is it completely different on every Windows installation, so I can't import it? Are there any other solutions except full Windows reinstall?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. **Important** note that, before making any changes to the registry, you should always back up the registry first. (I can't help running Windows10, sorry).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the values under this registry key are common to all Windows
installations, and some are created by installed applications.

Here is this registry key on my computer :

[image]

If you have enabled System Restore, rollback Windows to before
this registry modification was done.

Otherwise, to get you going, here is my export of this registry key.
Paste it inside a `.reg` file and double-click to insert.

Even if this helps with your immediate problem, you're sure to find
more problems in the future. Hopefully, someone might be able to
help you further when it arrives.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\DropboxExt]
@="{ECD97DE5-3C8F-4ACB-AEEE-CCAB78F7711C}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\NvAppShExt]
@="{A929C4CE-FD36-4270-B4F5-34ECAC5BD63C}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenContainingFolderMenu]
@="{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenGLShExt]
@="{E97DEC16-A50D-49bb-AE24-CF682282E08D}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\StartMenuExt]
@="{E595F05F-903F-4318-8B0A-7F633B520D2B}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@=""
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I omitted apps that I don't use and inserted only `OpenContainingFolderMenu`, `StartMenuExt`, and `{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` and that indeed fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any other solutions except full Windows reinstall?

Two possibilities:

(1) **First**, try a Windows 11 Repair Install and **Keep Everything**.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download. When done, run to create a USB key. Run Setup from the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

(2) **Repair does not fix the problem.**

In this latter case, damage to the OS and / or the Windows User Profile is too extensive to repair.

Best approach now is to back up and reinstall Windows fresh.

Comment: Yeah, that would be probably the best solution, but on the other hand, is much more time-consuming. Since I knew exactly what part of the registry I deleted I hope that restoring those values from other users will be enough (seems like it is because my issue is gone and I don't see any other problems). If I would observe any other issues then I will surely try this method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following lines to Notepad.Save the file as `lnkfile.reg`. Double-click on the REG file to run it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; OneDrive entry
; [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\ FileSyncEx]
; @="{CB3D0F55-BC2C-4C1A-85ED-23ED75B5106B}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\OpenContainingFolderMenu]
@="{37ea3a21-7493-4208-a011-7f9ea79ce9f5}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
@=""
```

The above are the entries seen in every Windows 11 computer. If you use OneDrive, uncomment the three lines by removing the semicolon and saving the file.

Comment: Thank you as well for confirming what entries should I put into the registry. You don't have it, but @harrymc also had `StartMenuExt` there and seems like it's also something coming from Windows and not from third-party apps, but I might be wrong here.

Comment: @xyz124: `StartMenuExt` is not added by Windows. It's a component of the "Classic Shell" program.

Comment: oh, that makes sense and is good to know. Thanks once again!